# MYSQL get multiple records if column value contains substring

Tags: mysql, arrays, database, string, join

I'm trying to pull data from a table that has column that contains a string array which holds tag ids,

values in column are in this format:

```
["22","17","35","21"]
```

I've tried implementing a SELF JOIN but I'm not very good in mysql so my query is returning a million results on a dataset that only have around 3000 records

my current attempt:

```
    SELECT
    users1.id AS `User Profile ID`,
    CASE
        WHEN users1.category = 'example-role-1' THEN 3 
        WHEN users1.category = 'example-role-2' THEN 4 
        ELSE ''
    END AS 'User Role',
    CASE
        WHEN INSTR( users2.opportunities, '22' ) > 0 THEN '22' 
        WHEN INSTR( users2.opportunities, '35' ) > 0 THEN '35' 
        ELSE ''
    END AS 'Role ID'
    FROM
        my_table_name users1, my_table_name users2
    WHERE
        (INSTR( users2.opportunities, '22' ) > 0
        OR
        INSTR( users2.opportunities, '35' ) > 0)
```

What I'm trying to do is pull data from an old system so it can be migrated to our new system, I know it would be really easy to do post-processing after values have been retrieved from the database but that is not an option as I'm running these queries on locally mounted database in XAMP and going to export the query results as CSV

Currently a single entry in the table is like this:

| id | category | tags |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | cat1 | ["22","35"] |

and I want my query to return something like this:

| id | category | tags |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | cat1 | 22 |
| 1 | cat1 | 35 |

So what can I modify in my query to get this result or do I need to change my approach?

Comment: Use according JSON function (JSON_CONTAINS, MEMBER OF and so on).

Comment: @Akina - values in that columns are not in JSON they are in a string `["22","35"]` like this

Comment: I see string value which is valid JSON array.